# .htaccess COMPLEX redirect and replace value + html

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, replace

I tried to search all pages but nothing to do for my request.
I need to REDIRECT the comlex link cause GOOGLE duplicate descriptions.

```
from:
http://www.3dstreaming.org/component/community/5816-stuart-edwards/profile.html?Itemid=0

to:
http://www.3dstreaming.org/you/edit-profile/5816-stuart-edwards.html
```

CONDICTIONS:

1. where "5816-stuart-edwards" is variable
2. part of the URL from "component/community" to "you/edit-profile"
3. replace from "5816-stuart-edwards/profile.html?Itemid=0" to "55816-stuart-edwards.html"

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/community/(.*)/profile.html$ /you/edit-profile/$1.html? [R]

RewriteRule ^you/edit-profile/(.*).html /component/community/$1/profile.html [L]
```

The above should change `http://www.3dstreaming.org/component/community/5816-stuart-edwards/profile.html?Itemid=0` to: `http://www.3dstreaming.org/you/edit-profile/5816-stuart-edwards.html`

Comment: nothig, it's the same, you can try by yourself got to http://www.3dstreaming.org/component/community/5816-stuart-edwards/profile.html?Itemid=0 it must to redirect to http://www.3dstreaming.org/you/edit-profile/5816-stuart-edwards.html but nothing...

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh, trying a different user or a different browser.

Comment: it's same, tried to http://www.3dstreaming.org/component/community/5912-deggial2005/profile.html?Itemid=0 | -->> I add "?Itemid=" to RewriteRule ^you/edit-profile/(.*).html /component/community/$1/profile.html [L] - but nothing again...

Comment: Is there any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: yes, but different " # Redirect from component/community/frontpage.html to community.html |
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+component/community/frontpage.html?[&\s] [NC] |
RewriteRule ^ /community.html? [R=301,L]

Comment: If you remove the other rules for a minute and try it, just to see if they are effecting it (they can be added back in once you know).

Comment: No problem, feel free to make it as correct so other people with your problem will know how you solved it.